# Java: download web content from Google https

Tags: java, https, download

I am trying to download the web content from Google https as in the link below.

[link to download](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=obxCUKm7Ic3GqAGvoYGIBQ&ved=0CDAQBSgA&q=pronunciation&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c5bfe0fbd78a3271&biw=1024&bih=759)

With the code below, I first disable the validation of certificates for testing purposes and trust all certificates, and then download the web as regular http, but for some reason, it is not successful:

```
public static void downloadWeb() {
        // Create a new trust manager that trust all certificates
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };

    // Activate the new trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection
                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {}

            //begin download as regular http
        try {
            String wordAddress = "https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=obxCUKm7Ic3GqAGvoYGIBQ&ved=0CDAQBSgA&q=pronunciation&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c5bfe0fbd78a3271&biw=1024&bih=759";
            URLConnection yc = new URL(wordAddress).openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine = "";
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(wordAddress);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {}

    }
```

Comment: Do you have to use Java?

Comment: yes, but do you have any recommendation on other language?

Comment: If I didn't have to use Java, I'd use `wget` or `cURL` and make a shell script (or batch file).

Comment: that is completely new to me. I will think about that, thanks a lot

Comment: On another note, Google's Terms of Service forbids automated queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fake HTTP headers so that google think that you are downloading it from a web browser. Here is a sample code using [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class App1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://_google_url_");
        httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0");
        HttpResponse execute = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        File file = new File("google.html");
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            execute.getEntity().writeTo(fout);
        } finally {
            if (fout != null) {
                fout.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Warning, I am not responsible if you use this code and violate Google's term of service agreement.

Comment: thanks, I just make some few queries. Do I need to install something from Apache?

Comment: HttpClient and HttpCore from the download link in the page link above.

Comment: I am able to get content from Google now, but what I want is the Dictionary page. For example, the dictionary page of word "pronuncation" https://www.google.com/search?q=download+pronunciation+google+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=pronunciation&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=wKdCUPnfJ4nZqgHi1IGADw&ved=0CB0QkQ4&fp=1&biw=1280&bih=721&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b&sei=IKlCUMbtOIGGqgH9xYGoDA

Comment: Google prevent you from doing that. The dictionary content is probably an ajax request which run dynamically. You might need to read the content you get from the downloaded page and the find out how google make ajax request and use that url to download your dictionary. Basically, it is fairly hard. what you want is probably google dictionary api http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html

Comment: this should be easier than downloading the google webpage yourself and it doesn't violate term and condition

Comment: The TOS has this bit, which seems to be relevant:
Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide.

Scrapers are likely "a method other than the interface provided".

Comment: That said, what are you actually trying to do?  It may be Google provides this in a much more stable API than what you're hacking together.

Comment: @DeanJ Should you be commenting on my answer? Maybe you wanted to comment on the question? I have already given a warning regarding TOS. I only provided the answer because it seems to be useful for others to know why it didn't work.